# JavaScript Uncaught TypeError: myTable is null

Tags: javascript, dom

I try to display elements of my database on my web page after loading it.
I fetch these elements using AJAX and it works fine.
The problem is  when I try to assign container (myTable) to put there my elements (`elementsOfDataBase`).
I get an error 'JavaScript Uncaught TypeError: myTable is null' in my console.
I use DOM `getElementById`. ID 'my-Table' is unique.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**myJs.js**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'myUrl/',
  success: function(response){
    console.log('success')
    let elementsOfDataBase = response.table
    const myTable = document.getElementById("my-Table");
    elementsOfDataBase.map(item => {
      const div = document.createElement('div')
      div.innerHTML += item.fields.item
      div.innerHTML += '<br>'
      myTable.appendChild(div);
    })
  },
  error: function (error){
    console.log('error')
  },
})
```

**home.html**

```
<div id="my-Table"></div>
```

Comment: The provided code snippet doesn't fire the given error, `myElement` doesn't occur in the example.

Comment: There is no myElement in this piece of code

Comment: The element with id of `my-Table` doesn't exist at the time you're referring it. Why is that is not clear, the example is not wide enough. Please add some code so that we can reproduce the issue. Also, don't use `map` just to iterate an array, `forEach` exists for that task.

Comment: I resolved it.  `<div id="my-Table"></div>` was at the bottom  of my html file. When I put it higher it started working.  I'm really new in Js and I don't know  how this exactly works but now all is displaying as i want. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

IMO you try to access the table before it's rendered.
Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Your code
});
```